# displaying list value inside dictionary inside list

Tags: python

I have a data set that is a list of dictionaries that have a value of a list.

ex:

```
a = 
[
   {'node1':[1,2,3]},...,..
]
```

I was wondering how can I access the 1 or 2 inside `node1`? I know that if I did a[0][0] I would display {'node1':[1,2,3]}. I thought `a[0][0][0]` would display 1 but I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: you need to access the dictionary properly e.g. a[0]['node1'][0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `a[0]['node1'][0]`. You can refer to an item in dict by its key (which is 'node1' in your case). Indexes like [0] do not make sense in dictionaries, as their items don't have a specified order.
Note that your `a[0][0]` example should also result an error. a[0] is what returns the first dict in your list: `{'node1':[1,2,3]}`

Answer (score 4):

`a[number]` is one of your dictionaries, i.e. `{'node1': [1, 2, 3], 'node2': [4, 5, 6]}`.

Now, `a[number]['node1']` returns the list belonging to `'node1'`, i.e. [1, 2, 3]. You can access the list normally.

So the complete expression would be

```
a[0]['node1'][0]
>>> 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to index into the dictionary using the name of the key, in this case `'node1'`:

```
>>> a = [{'node1':[1,2,3]}]
>>> a[0]['node1'][0]
1
```

Answer (score 1):

a = [ {'node1':[1, 2, 3]} ]

```
>>> a[0]['node1'][0]
```

a[0] selects the first element in the list which is the map {'node1': [1, 2, 3]}. Then a[0]['node1'] selects the value of the map with key 'node1'. Finally a[0]['node1'][0] selects the first element from the list which is the value for the key from map. This gives 1.

for getting the value 2

```
>>> a[0]['node1'[1]
```

Change the index accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this:

```
a[0]['node1'][...]
```